# AS3 duplicated MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

In my app I'm importing movieclips from library to the stage like this :

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class MainTimeline extends MovieClip {

    //Variabili
    public var VFullscreen: int = 1;

    //Import var        
    public var VTerminal: Terminal = new Terminal();
    public var nTerminal:String;

    public function MainTimeline(): void {

        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;

        //Import

        //Terminal
        VTerminal.x = 288;
        VTerminal.y = 384;
        stage.addChild(VTerminal);


        //Event Listeners
        //addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_BringToFront);
        VTerminal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_WindowDrag);
        VTerminal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_WindowDrop);
    }

    //public functions

    //Gestione Fullscreen

    public function fl_Fullscreen(event: MouseEvent): void {
        switch (VFullscreen) {
            case 0:
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
                VFullscreen = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
                VFullscreen = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    public function fl_FSCheck(event: Event): void {
        if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
            VFullscreen = 0;
        }
        if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE) {
            VFullscreen = 1;
        }
    }

    //Primo Piano Finestre
    public function fl_BringToFront(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.addChild(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
    }


    public function fl_WindowDrag(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.currentTarget.startDrag();
        nTerminal = event.currentTarget.name.toString();
        trace(nTerminal);
    }

    public function fl_WindowDrop(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    }

    //Chiusura
    public function fl_Close(event: MouseEvent): void {
        stage.nativeWindow.close();
    }

    //Apertura/Chiusura Terminal
    public function fl_Terminal(event: MouseEvent): void {
        if (contains(VTerminal)) {
            removeChild(VTerminal);
        } else {
            VTerminal.x = 288;
            VTerminal.y = 320;
            addChild(VTerminal);
        }
    }

}
```

}

But I've a strange bug that I've never seen. It had the same MC twice and, in the runtime, when i drag and drop it I can see 2 MC one named `instance8` and one `instance45`. I don't know how to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

TERMINAL CLASS

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.text.TextField;


public class Terminal extends MovieClip {

    public var version: String = "Verison 0.0.1 a";

    public function Terminal(event: Event) {
        //Varie
        nome.text = "terminal";
        vOut.text = version;

        //Animazioni
        loader0.gotoAndPlay(1);
        loader1.gotoAndPlay(25);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing. Where did you put this code? How is drag and drop implemented?

Comment: Could you show your whole code ? And verify if don't have already an instance that you have inserted manually to the Stage.

Comment: I've edited with the full code and yes, there's not the instance in the stage

Comment: To have two, there must a either a `new` keyword somewhere or something placed on the timeline.   Perhaps show your Terminal class.  And this code is your document class right?

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer sorry, could you please clarify your statement "_yes, there's not the instance in the stage_"? Do you already have an instance on the stage that you dragged there from the library, for example?

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer - Please share your Terminal class, and triple check that you do NOT have an instance of `Terminal` on any frames in your FlashPro timeline .   Sharing your entire project may also help if you're still stuck and comfortable with sharing it all.

Comment: I've added Terminal class, I haven't an instance on the stage dragged from the library, I've only one frame and it's empty. I've also a third class with only some addEventListener statements to call buttons functions

Comment: Can zip up your project and share a link to it?

Comment: My project https://www.dropbox.com/s/bddc7ylfqz7dod6/Flash.zip?dl=0

Comment: If I delete your menu layer, the copy goes away.  You probably have an instance of the terminal somewhere down the line on that object.   So back to the "tripple check that you do NOT have an instance of Terminal on any frames in your FlashPro timelines"

Comment: I don't know, after cutting the menu MC the frame is void

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, the statement

```
//Primo Piano Finestre
public function fl_BringToFront(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.addChild(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
}
```

when the mouseDown and mouseUp event finished, the mouseEvent.click event will trigger, so you will get another instance

Comment: This is just a cast. There is no new instance created.

Comment: It can't be that function because I've the same problem without that

Comment: `this.addChild` doesn't create another instance.  If the object you add is already added to a different parent, it will be moved.  If it is already added to the same parent, it will just be moved to the top most layer.  **It will not be copied**